# CSS is not being connected to HTML Flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm writing a site for Flask and faced the problem that the css-file does not connect to the project

This is HTML-file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/main.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This is CSS-file:

```
body {
background: red;
}
```

But the color never appeared on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is, if your static file is in templates file remove it from templates and do that:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

css_file = "static/styles/style.css"
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
   return render_template("index.html", css_link = css_file)
```

then in your head tag you add:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{css_link}}" type="text/css"/>
```

Don't forget to add a body tag!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<body></body>` to your html document